# visual studio does not give error if a header is missing

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-studio

I am testing with a simple test program right now. It looks like below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string s = "a b c d ";
    remove(s.begin(),s.end(),' ');
}
```

When i build it with visual studio, it builds correctly and does not give any error. However if i try to build it with eclipse (mingw), it complains about the functions 'remove', as it should because the corresponding header is not included. 
Is there a way to configure visual studio such that it will also complain and not auto-include headers or whatever fancy thing it is doing? I have already checked by disabling the option to use pre-compiled headers in visual studio project properties, and that doesn't help.

Comment: AFAIK there is nothing you can do.  `<iostream>` is allowed to include `<string>` and if that is what MSVS does then there is "nothing" wrong with the code.  Really what you need is some sort of static analyzer or a code review process for this.

Comment: but in that case i shouldn't get any error with eclipse mingw either! Why do I have to explicitly include it there then?

Comment: eclipse is a different compiler.  Different compilers structure there include files differently.

Comment: When it comes to static analyzers it seems like it's possible to build the tool `include-what-you-use` for Windows ([Issue #684](https://github.com/include-what-you-use/include-what-you-use/issues/684)). - but it also seems like it's a lot of work. That tool can be used to warn about missing headers and headers that you don't need, but it sometimes makes mistakes. It's a little awkward to use it properly i.m.o.

Comment: And here is the comments from GCC team about Porting to GCC10: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/porting_to.html "As such, C++ programs that used components defined in <stdexcept> or <string> without explicitly including the right headers will no longer compile."

Answer (score 0):

When you write a program that fails to include the proper headers, some toolchains may still *just so happen* to successfully build your program, because maybe their `<iostream>` happens to ultimately include the header you need ([like `<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)).

That doesn't change the fact that your code is wrong. You're getting a build by chance.

You don't configure another toolchain to do that. You fix your code to include the correct headers.

So:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
```

Answer (score 0):

The C++ Standard does not define, that a certain file needs to be included for the contained definitions to be able to be used.

It only defines in which files the specific functions are defined.

So if the specific implementation which You use includes everything through a file and You don't need to include anything else, than that is still allowed by the Standard.

So in one implementation, everything will compile, while in another errors will appear.
This is not controlled by the C++ Standard.

What You can do is file a bug to the implementors, and see if they agree that it's a bug. (In this case: https://github.com/microsoft/stl/issues)

Comment: It's definitely not a bug though.